# Maximum and Minimum values of the HoughCircles function in openCV

Tags: python, opencv, hough-transform, houghcircles

I use this image 
[image] Foto de [rupixen.com](https://unsplash.com/es/@rupixen?utm_content=creditCopyText&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=unsplash) en [Unsplash](https://unsplash.com/es/fotos/monedas-redondas-de-color-dorado-liTBV5RQdbQ?utm_content=creditCopyText&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=unsplash)

I can't understand what the maximum and minimum values of the HoughCircles function in openCV

So that it encloses all the coins. When I set dp to zero an error appears that it cannot be zero, but it is never zero because I add +1 to each trackbar

[image]

And when I change the values of the trackbar for example maxR, this error appears:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rint'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/noemi/Escritorio/morphology/hougbarra.py", line 43, in <module>
    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 200, in around
  File "/home/noemi/Escritorio/morphology/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 3337, in around
    return _wrapfunc(a, 'round', decimals=decimals, out=out)
  File "/home/noemi/Escritorio/morphology/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 54, in _wrapfunc
    return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
  File "/home/noemi/Escritorio/morphology/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 43, in _wrapit
    result = getattr(asarray(obj), method)(*args, **kwds)
TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type NoneType which has no callable rint method
```

This is the code I'm using

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

def nada(x):
    pass

image = cv2.imread("money.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
filas, columnas, _ = image.shape
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

#Crear la ventana y barras delizantes
cv2.namedWindow("Hough con barras")
cv2.createTrackbar("dp", "Hough con barras", 1, 100, nada)
cv2.createTrackbar("minDist", "Hough con barras", 1, 100, nada)
cv2.createTrackbar("minR", "Hough con barras", 50, 100, nada)
cv2.createTrackbar("maxR", "Hough con barras", 10, 100, nada)
cv2.createTrackbar("param1", "Hough con barras", 100, 100, nada)
cv2.createTrackbar("param2", "Hough con barras", 100, 100, nada)

while True:
    img2 = image.copy()
    dpd = cv2.getTrackbarPos("dp", "Hough con barras") + 1
    minDist = cv2.getTrackbarPos("minDist", "Hough con barras") + 1
    param1 = cv2.getTrackbarPos("param1", "Hough con barras") + 1
    param2 = cv2.getTrackbarPos("param2", "Hough con barras") + 1
    minR = cv2.getTrackbarPos("minR", "Hough con barras") +1
    maxR = cv2.getTrackbarPos("maxR", "Hough con barras") + 1

    # Find circles with HoughCircles
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(thresh, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, int(dpd), int(columnas / minDist), param1=int(param1), param2=int(param2),
                               minRadius=int(columnas / minR), maxRadius=int(columnas / maxR))
    #Encontrar y dibujar contorna
    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
    for i in circles[0, :]:
        # draw the outer circle
        cv2.circle(img2, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 255, 0), 2)
        # draw the center of the circle
        cv2.circle(img2, (i[0], i[1]), 2, (0, 0, 255), 3)

    cv2.imshow("Hough con barras", img2)
    #cv2.imshow("Contornos", img2)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("s"):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The trackbars will be useful to review the appropriate values of each parameter but I don't understand how to set the values of each parameter

Comment: That exception happens because when `HoughCircles` doesn't find anything it returns `None`. You don't handle that situation and proceed to the next line where you then have a call to `np.around(circles)` -- i.e. `np.around(None)`, and that's not valid.

Comment: Beside that, what is the rationale for the following calculations when settings parameters of `HoughCircles` -- `minRadius=int(columnas / minR), maxRadius=int(columnas / maxR)`. Why is that division there? Same for the `minDist`....

Comment: Also, you should not make the max value smaller than the min value!

Comment: @fmw42 True, but in this case, thanks to that reciprocal, it does have have to be that way.

Comment: @Dan Mašek  Thanks for the correction. I had not noticed that. I had just looked at the trackbar figure.  Sorry for being so sloppy.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I try to repair the code, but I still have some concerns. In which cases does HoughCircles return None?  I add this ```if circles is not None:``` and ```else:  break``` I can't see the errors anymore but is not a solution because I still don't understand in which situations I get None or how to avoid getting none . Additionally, I used the divisions because in the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d70/tutorial_hough_circle.html) implemented and was testing with several values.